# How to get CoreData attributes from a ViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a simple CoreData stack with a CoreData class `Booking`, that I want to use in a ViewController. I want to get each record of `Booking` and use the `data` attribute from each to put events in a calendar view controller.

I found this code that is supposed to get CoreData entities and it seems to be ok - I just don't know how to use this data beyond this point, in a loop getting the `Booking.date` attribute and printing it for example.

I have this in my `ViewController` Class:

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Booking.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Booking.id, ascending: false)
        ]
    ) var bookings: FetchedResults<Booking>
```

There are no errors with this, however I cannot be sure this is actually getting data from the `Booking` entity because I don't know how to use whatever this is returning.

I have tried just using `print(bookings)` in my `override func loadView()` method. It crashes when it his that print statement, seemingly because it's `nil` and wasn't unwrapped - but when I try to unwrap it nothing works.

I figured I must be doing something wrong with the way I'm grabbing `Bookings` from CoreData, but I just can't tell what it is that's wrong. Is there a specific way to access this data from a `ViewController`

Note I have all of the necessary setup done in `AppDelegate` for `NSPersistantContainer` and `saveContext`. I have managed to use `CoreData` in other areas of my code so I know that aspect of it is working properly. It's just confusing me in this `ViewController`

Comment: If you really use *ViewController Class* then none of those property wrappers works properly (if at all works), because they are designed for SwiftUI views only.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I didn't realize that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an `FetchedResultsController` in an `ObservableObject` that serves as your Manager/ViewModel can help.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller

An `@Published var bookings` would get updated by the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`'s method `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html

Using a shared instance of the `ObservableObject` via a singleton pattern or other patterns will enable you to share data between a `ViewController` and a SwiftUI `View`.

I made this video for another question a while ago that shows the basic setup. of the `FetchedResultsController`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U-4Zon6dbE

Comment: For my calendar component I am using a `UIViewController` class. Can I use an `ObservableObject` in that? I am also using UIViewControllerRepresentable to show it in a SwiftUI stack. If Observable Object is only to be used in SwiftUI I'm not sure how to get the CoreData entities into my `UIViewController` class.

Comment: `@ObservedObject` can only be used in SwiftUI to update the `UIViewController` you would use the `FetchedResultsController` in the traditional sense (described in the second link. The `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` updates both the `ObservableObject` and your `UIViewController`.